# Point "Localhost2" at a new folder in tomcat

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a one project named "Demo" in jsp/servlet and i am using apache tomcat server to run the project.

when i type "localhost" in the browser , it run and open the project
now what i need is that when i type "localhost2" then it should open a folder named as "temp" located in the demo project.

Anybody have any idea, help me

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve what you want with 2 steps:

1. add an entry in `/etc/hosts` file, I assume you are running a *nix OS, it should be `127.0.0.1 localhost2`
2. add a virtual host in the tomcat config file, which is located in `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml`, add the following between the `<Engine>` tag:

   ```
   <Host name="localhost2"  appBase="" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
           <Context docBase="/root/path/to/your/demo/project" path="" reloadable="true" />                                                                    
   </Host>
   ```

Comment: That is very close to the correct answer but actually creates a huge security hole. By setting appBase="" you set appBase==$CATALINA_BASE. That means all the directories under $CATALINA_BASE (bin, conf, lib, work, temp, webapps) will be deployed as web applications to the localhost2 virtual host. That exposes the entire contents of /conf including server.xml and all the web.xml files for all webapps. Setting appBase="webapps-localhost2" (even if that dir does not exist) would fix the security hole.

Comment: @MarkThomas, Thanks for pointing out that, you are right. `appBase` must be set to a directory that contains only web applications(folders that contain a `WEB-INF` folder and a `web.xml` file in it).